# how to set three images on/off/pause on button in table view and get value accordingly in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton, tableview

I need to place three images **on/off/pause** on button  in cycle manner .I have created a custom cell with a button and label. I need to get the value of cell according to image pressed on button.

the button cycle is like :

> on ->off-->pause-->on-->off

the default state is pause.

Comment: post some code wht u tried ?

Comment: give the button tag and using the tag you can check which button is clicked

Comment: i have only one  button on custom cell,i need to maintain three states on/off/pause on it...

Comment: @megha I would say it will much better you should post your code what your tried to achieve this, and you will get more help from community, coz I have done this kind of task using **If-Else** etc. but without knowing your code it's bit hard to post you appropriate code snip.FYI you

Comment: i think you have to use UIsegmentcontrol for it

Comment: @RDC i have managed two states on/off on uibutton ,but i dnt get any idea for assiging three images on that button... For on/off image on button i used   [self setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"off.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"on.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];  but does get idea for third image.

Comment: @megha see define the tags for all these three states and then you need to update the icon and tag in your button's click method after fetching previous Tag value (button state)

Comment: @megha glad to know that,btw I was just created a sample code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  if ([cell.button.currentImage isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"on.png"] ]){

     // set off image
   }
  else if([cell.button.currentImage isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"off.png"] ]){
      // set pause image
   }
 else{
        // set ON image
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds the job for your controller.

The controller will ideally have the information to know what state to set a button to in the cell -- how else can you create the cell (in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`) in the first place?

When the state needs to change (whenever a button is pressed?), you can have your controller call `reloadData` (or one of the more fine-grained per-row or per-section methods) on its tableview to update the UI.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a subclass of UIButton with multiple values of some property with enum type and delegate method, where you can change cell's label text according to changing state of the button.

```
typedef enum {
  TriButtonValueOn,
  TriButtonValueOff,
  TriButtonValuePause
} TriButtonValue

@class TriButton;

@protocol TriButtonDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)triButtonStateChanged:(TriButton *)button;

@end

@interface TriButton:UIButton
@property (nonatomic,retain) id<TriButtonDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic) TriButtonValue currentState;
```

Meanwhile in the .m file of TriButton

```
-(void)setCurrentState:(TriButtonValue)value{
  switch(value){
    case TriButtonValueOn:
      self.image = ...
      break;
    case TriButtonValueOff:
      self.image = ...
      break;
      ...
   ...
  }
  [self.delegate triButtonStateChanged:self];
}
```

In your viewController's delegate method

```
-(void)triButtonStateChanded:(TriButton *)button{
  UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[button superview];
  UILabel *textLbl = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:tagOfLabel];
  [textLbl setText:@"state change to ..."]; //set it according to button.currentState
}
```

Comment: thanks for ur answer...it is  also a good answer...

Answer (score 1):

try this....

```
    -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
    {
            static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"SearchUserCustomCell";
            SearchUserCustomCell *cell = (SearchUserCustomCell *)[tblUser dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            if(cell == nil) 
            {
                    NSArray* nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SearchUserCustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
                    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
                    cell.showsReorderControl = NO;
                    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
                    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
                    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
                    [cell.button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            }
            cell.button.tag = indexpath.row;
    }
```

and button click method....

```
    -(IBAction) buttonClick:(id)sender {
            UIButton *button = (UIButton *) sender;

            if (button.imageView.image == [UIImage imageNamed:@"on.png"]) 
            {
                    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"off.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }
            else if  (button.imageView.image == [UIImage imageNamed:@"off.png"]) 
            {
                    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }
            …..
    }
```

Comment: i have done the same code ....thanku so much for your answer...